# Windows 7 search of NAS devices

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, nas

I have a ReadyNas Duo both at home and at work.  I find that it is difficult to perform quick searches of the data, looking for files with keywords in them.  Windows search does not seem to want to index and search them, except through the old methods that take forever.  What is the best way to make these NAS devices quickly searchable?  Google Desktop Search? others? Something built into Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Desktop search is being discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Many NAS devices use the open source samba software to share files with windows. Samba does not implement Windows Search Protocol(WSP).  https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/SoC/Ideas#Windows_Search_Protocol_WSP_client_library_and_torture_tests

If you need Windows Search on your NAS, buy a NAS device that is based on Windows. Microsoft sells a version of Windows Server called Windows Storage Server which is distributed only via partners. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/storage-server.aspx

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a tool that will search samba servers, not to be told not to use samba servers.  I too would like such a recommendation.